# Interview went great, HR is not following up, should I follow up with a call?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, hiring-process, follow-up

I went to a great company. There I had 5 interviews taken place by different people. I think all of them went really good, they seems impressed with me, one of them said that I have good knowledge. The last interview was with the director, he said that

`"the result is positive and you can be sure you will hear something positive from us maybe tomorrow or the max by monday"`.

The interview was on thursday the 25th of dec (christmas). No followup came on monday and today is wednesday.

I emailed a thank you letter, saying the position is of my interests and I am looking forward for the next conversation. But, no reply till yet.

Should I follow up with a call?

Comment: You did five interviews on Christmas Day...!?

Comment: @sevenseacat I meant 5 rounds of interview.

Answer (score 5):

No, not yet purely because of the holiday period.

I would leave it until Friday before you make further contact.  This particular period is the most stressful (beyond year end results) for all employees and holidays/absences can significantly impact the normal timings for standard actions.

It wouldn't go against you *per se* to make contact today but I normally err on the side of caution when giving people leeway.

Extenuating circumstances may have occurred at the company which require dealing with prior to offering you the role.

In my mind, Friday seems a reasonable amount of time to wait before contact.

If no contact has been returned to you by next week then I would press a little harder and say a version of the following -

> I really want to work at Company X and the team seem like the kind of people I would get on really well with so I hope the outcome of my interview is positive.  However, if not, could you provide feedback as I have been invited to explore other opportunities.

Comment: As the interview actually occurred on Christmas Day, I suspect the company in question is not following the typical Western holidays.

Comment: I suspect as much as well but in light of more information I had to assume that was the delay rather than the alternative...

Comment: Well .. lots of employees were there on that day.. also company is in india.

Comment: OK.  I get the impression from your comment you are going to contact them anyway; please let us know how it goes.  Good luck @Ishmeet

Comment: @Venture2099 So I called him up, he told me to come on tuesday the next week, for a meeting with the manager. I thought that it would be for signing offer letter as all five rounds are done now. However, it was another technical interview, and after it, there was another technical interview. Then, the guy told me to leave, and said they will contact me (huh! yeah they would). My guess is they called me for another 5 rounds of technical interview, and this time I got rejected on the second round.